# exporting console.log from a module in node.js

Tags: node.js, console.log

I'm using a customized version of [node-clim](https://github.com/epeli/node-clim), but I want to put away all the customization code in a module of its own and `require()` it in my main app. But I can't seem to do that..

This code works

```
var util = require('util');
var clim = require('clim')
clim.logWrite = function(level, prefixes, msg) {
    ...
    customizing code
    ...
    process.stderr.write(...);
};

var console = clim();

console.log('hey'); // works
```

But in trying to put the above in a separate file `clim.js` and exporting the console object...

```
module.export = console;
```

and `require()`ing it in my main app doesn't work..

```
var console = require('./clim');
console.log('hey');
//      ^ TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'log'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
module.export = console;
```

to

```
module.exports = console;
```